# Gentoo emerge a package gives 404s - Do I need to --sync?

Tags: linux, package-management, gentoo

I've got a gentoo server here. It hasn't been upgraded in a good long while. I just tried to emerge a package, and it tries to download things, but all fails with 404. I can get other web access fine.

Do I need to do an `emerge --sync`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ebuild is most likely pointing to an old file that has been removed. An `emerge --sync` should fix the problem, but if it doesn't you can try downloading the file manually and placing it in `/usr/portage/distfiles`

Answer (score 3):

maybe your GENTOO_MIRRORS line in /etc/make.conf is out of date?  check that the mirror is [still active](http://www.gentoo.org/main/en/mirrors2.xml)?