# Can't emerge fish - dependency htmlview returns 404 or fails on rmd160 verification

Tags: linux, gentoo

Does anyone know how to fix this? I've tried running emerge --sync, but that didn't have any effect. When I download the file manually and move it to /usr/portage/distfiles, I get the error "Failed on RMD160 verification".

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer in another thread!

[Gentoo emerge a package gives 404s - Do I need to --sync?](https://serverfault.com/questions/50989/gentoo-emerge-a-package-gives-404s-do-i-need-to-sync)

All I needed to do was change my GENTOO_MIRRORS line in /etc/make.conf